# macro parameter pack with boost preprocessor

Tags: c++, c++03, boost-preprocessor

I don't know there similar question, or not.

How to simplify

```
(a == 78 || a == 98 || a == 73 || a == 11 || a == 90 || a==103 || a==45 )
```

expression to

```
MY_CHECK(a, (78, 98, 73, 11, 90, 103, 45) )
```

With boost preprocessor ??
Is there any ready solution in boost preprocessor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find better than a transform followed by a fold, since `BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOLD_LEFT` does not carry a `data` parameter around. Still:

```
#define MY_CHECK_FOLD_OR(s, a, b) a || b
#define MY_CHECK_FOLD_EQ(s, var, elem) (var) == (elem)

#define MY_CHECK(var, values)             \
    (BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOLD_LEFT(              \
        MY_CHECK_FOLD_OR, false,          \
        BOOST_PP_SEQ_TRANSFORM(           \
            MY_CHECK_FOLD_EQ, var,        \
            BOOST_PP_TUPLE_TO_SEQ(values) \
        )                                 \
    ))
```

... which expands:

```
if (MY_CHECK(a, (1, 2, 3)))
```

... into:

```
if ((false || (a) == (1) || (a) == (2) || (a) == (3)))
```

[See it live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/77018f7cda6d4f55)

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to use the preprocessor here. A *variadic template* will do just fine. Here's an example using a C++17 *fold expression*:

```
template <typename Needle, typename... Haystack>
bool my_check(const Needle& needle, const Haystack&... haystack)
{
    return ((needle == haystack) || ...);
}
```

[**live example on wandbox**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/ZdBHI6XDKsEBoQ2l)

Comment: Thanks, but I use c++03 only. [c++03] added.

Comment: I thought that c++ tag means old c++03 )), sorry.

Comment: It's 2018 @KhurshidNormuradov, you shouldn't even be using C++03. At the minimum you should be using C++11.

Comment: I write code for old server. I   like c++11, c++14, sure.